# Installing ODBC 18 driver on Amazon Linux

Tags: amazon-ec2, odbc, amazon-linux

I see instructions from MS site on how to install ODBC drivers on various Linux distributions but not for Amazon Linux.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15&tabs=redhat18-install%2Calpine17-install%2Cdebian8-install%2Credhat7-13-install%2Crhel7-offline

Has anyone installed this driver on AWS EC2 with Amazon Linux?  Which script should be used for it?

Answer (score 1):

on Amazon Linux 2 you can use the RHEL and Oracle Linux instructions

```
#RHEL 9
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/rhel/9.0/prod.repo > /etc/yum.repos.d/mssql-release.repo

exit
sudo yum remove unixODBC-utf16 unixODBC-utf16-devel #to avoid conflicts
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y yum install -y msodbcsql18
# optional: for bcp and sqlcmd
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y yum install -y mssql-tools18
```